# Analytic solution to explicit midpoint rule applied to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

By solving a three-term recurrence relation, calculate analytically the sequence of values {$y_n:n=2,3,4,...$} that is generated by the explicit midpoint rule: $y_{n+2}=y_n+2hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ when it is applied to the ODE: $y'=-y$, $t\geq0$.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: What is $f$?  Once you see that, your "explicit midpoint rule" is the three-term recurrence relation.  Look for solutions of the form $y_n = c r^n$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. If this we're a one-step method, such as the Euler method, then my $f$ would simply be $f(t,y)=-y$. But as this is a two-step method I am not sure what to do.

Comment: The differential equation is supposed to be $y' = f(t,y)$, right?

Comment: Ahh I see, then the recurrence relation will give $y_n = A(-h+\sqrt{h^2+1})^n + B(-h-\sqrt{h^2+1})^n$. Thank you!!